# Is this the best way to add a many to many when you require the id that you don't have yet?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EventsCoreApi.Models.Entities
{
    public partial class Event
    {
        public Event()
        {

```
        EventHasMusicGenre = new HashSet<EventHasMusicGenre>();
    }

    public uint EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] StartTime { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PolicyMinimumAge { get; set; }
    public string PolicyDescription { get; set; }
    public uint DressCodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DressCode DressCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventHasMusicGenre> EventHasMusicGenre { get; set; }'    




 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Event>> PostEvent(EventDto eventFromClient)
    {
        var newEvent = new Event
        {
            Name = eventFromClient.Name,
            StartDate = eventFromClient.StartDate,
            EndDate = eventFromClient.EndDate,
            StartTime = eventFromClient.StartTime,
            EndTime = eventFromClient.StartTime,
            Description = eventFromClient.Description,
            DressCodeId = eventFromClient.DressCodeId,
            PolicyMinimumAge = eventFromClient.PolicyMinimumAge,
            PolicyDescription = eventFromClient.PolicyDescription
        };


        _context.Event.Add(newEvent);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            EventHasMusicGenre music1 = new EventHasMusicGenre()
            {
                EventId = newEvent.EventId,
                MusicGenreId = eventFromClient.MusicGenres[0].MusicGenreId
            };

        EventHasMusicGenre music2 = new EventHasMusicGenre()
        {
            EventId = newEvent.EventId,
            MusicGenreId = eventFromClient.MusicGenres[1].MusicGenreId
        };


        await _eventHasMusicGenresRepository.PostEventHasMusicGenre(music1);

        await _eventHasMusicGenresRepository.PostEventHasMusicGenre(music2);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**I have to create an event object who has a many to many relationship so the linking table will be eventHasMusicGenre who has it s own repo and methods is this best way to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this pattern is fine, however see below for alternative:

```
List<EventHasMusicGenre> genres = new List<EventHasMusicGenre>();//declare list

foreach(var g in eventFromClient.MusicGenres)//loop client array
{
  genres.Add(new EventHasMusicGenre(){//add to list
    MusicGenreId = g.MusicGenreId
  })
}

var newEvent = new Event
    {
        Name = eventFromClient.Name,
        StartDate = eventFromClient.StartDate,
        EndDate = eventFromClient.EndDate,
        StartTime = eventFromClient.StartTime,
        EndTime = eventFromClient.StartTime,
        Description = eventFromClient.Description,
        DressCodeId = eventFromClient.DressCodeId,
        PolicyMinimumAge = eventFromClient.PolicyMinimumAge,
        PolicyDescription = eventFromClient.PolicyDescription,
        MusicGenres : [ genres ] //list as part of model, no need to worry about the id
    };
```

This way you dont have to hardcode indices

Comment: **Thanks  @Vince Could you share full implementation including context save changes ? I have inside event only eventHasMusicGenre collection and single musicgenre navigation property. Also I need an event id to fill eventhasMusicGenreI am sharing the full model.**